# Write to a specific line in txt file when the line is empty

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I am working on file writing in Vb.net. I know how to override a specific line in a text file but when it is empty or equal to "" ,  it fails.

I tried with

```
Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("filepath")
lines(4) = "to replace text"
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines)
```

It shows a Index out of array exception. It might be because the line in the file is empty.

Thank you

Comment: If its an array exception based on this code uv shown its because lines(4) doesnt exist maybe ...

Comment: what is in the input file?

Comment: filepath is the path of the input file